# Retrieve only top % of sub group in a data.frame

Tags: r

I need to retrieve the top % of a sub group in a `data.frame`. The key is that subgroups have different lengths, so I can't choose an arbitrary rank to size the group subset. I do already have a rank column that is correctly ordered.

```
vartype varname rank
a       one       1
a       two       2
b       one       1
b       two       2
b       three     3
b       four      4
c       one       1
c       two       2
c       three     3
```

Selecting the top 50% of **rank** for each **vartype** in the above table would return:

```
vartype varname rank
a       one     1
b       one     1
b       two     2
c       one     1
c       two     2
```

It doesn't really matter if it uses floor or ceiling for cutoff. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, you say you already have them ordered in the column `rank`. Then it's just a matter of choosing the first `n` out of `N` rows, for each group, where `n = ceiling(N/2)`.

Assuming `dat` is your data.frame, using `data.table` it's just:

```
setDT(dat)[, .SD[seq_len(ceiling(.N/2))], by=vartype]
#    vartype varname rank
# 1:       a     one    1
# 2:       b     one    1
# 3:       b     two    2
# 4:       c     one    1
# 5:       c     two    2
```

Comment: I should delete mine probably :) Was hoping you asleep

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind using **dplyr**:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "vartype varname rank
 a       one       1
 a       two       2
 b       one       1
 b       two       2
 b       three     3
 b       four      4
 c       one       1
 c       two       2
 c       three     3",header = TRUE,sep = "")

> dat %>% group_by(vartype) %>% filter(percent_rank(rank) <= 0.5)
Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: vartype

  vartype varname rank
1       a     one    1
2       b     one    1
3       b     two    2
4       c     one    1
5       c     two    2
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a method using base functions

```
dd[with(dd, ave(rank, vartype, FUN=function(x) x<=median(x)))==1, ]
```

We use `ave` to see which ranks are greater than the median for each group and we select where those are true (`==1`).

Comment: That didn't give the desired output when I tried this

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks. I had the inequality the wrong way. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with `data.table` for example

```
temp <- read.table(text = 
"vartype varname rank
a       one       1
a       two       2
b       three     1
b       four      2
b       one       3
b       two       4
c       one       1
c       two       2
c       three     3", header = T)


library(data.table)
setDT(temp)[, list(rank = rank[seq_len(ceiling(length(rank)/2))],
                   varname = varname[seq_len(ceiling(length(rank)/2))]), by = vartype]

#    vartype rank varname
# 1:       a    1     one
# 2:       b    1     one
# 3:       b    2     two
# 4:       c    1     one
# 5:       c    2     two
```